# NavigationMixin.Navigate how to handle onsuccess function?

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigation, navigationmixin.navigate

currently I need some specific logic which requires using NavigationMixin onsuccess event. I spent some time and can’t find any info if it is possible at all
Here is my sample of code

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__objectPage',
        attributes: {
            objectApiName: this.__PrimaryObjectApi,
            actionName: 'new'
        },
        state: {
            defaultFieldValues: defaultValues
        }
    })
```

Will appreciate any help and additional info

Comment: Please explain, what you are trying to do and what is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Navigate Mixin does not have any onsuccess method
2. But It returns a promise
3. Something like this
4. List item

   ```
   this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({

      type: 'standard__objectPage',
       attributes: {
          objectApiName: this.__PrimaryObjectApi,
          actionName: 'new'
      },
      state: {
          defaultFieldValues: defaultValues
      }}).then((url) => {
        this.recordPageUrl = url;
     });
   ```
5. So you need to handle the promise using **then** block
6. This would mean that the NavigateMixin was executed succesfully
7. Else you need to append a **catch** block which means a error was thrown and the promise was rejected.

Comment: This answer only deals with GenerateUrl ,but the function in the question ( and the one I am also looking for an answer to) is for Navigate. That does not seem to return a promise unfortunately.